# NSMutableArray componentsJoinedByString behaving strangely in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am trying to create a keyboard in my app, where you press the key, it adds the letter to an array, then the array joins the entries into a string and sets it as the text in a textField.

Here is an example key:

```
if ([self.name isEqualToString:@"a.png"])
{
    [self.savedNameCharacterArray addObject:@"A"];
    self.savedNameString = [self.savedNameCharacterArray componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    [self.manager.areYouSureLabel setText:self.savedNameString];
}
```

"savedNameCharacterArray is an NSMutableArray,  "savedNameString" is just a string, and "areYouSureLabel" a textField.

When I tap the "A" key repeatedly, it will output "A,A,A", like it should.  But if I then tap the "B" key, it will not say "A,A,A,B", but instead "B".  Even more strangely, if I then tap the "A" key again, it will now say "A,A,A,A". And if I tap "B" again, it will say "B,B".  Do you know what could be happening?

Comment: What class is this code in? How many instances of this class do you have in the running app?

Comment: The problem you're having likely has little to do with this block of code, but rather in the outer scope that it's in. Can you give more code/context?

Comment: need more details, unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Oh i realize what's wrong now.  Every key has it's own savedNameCharacterArray.  I'm sorry for wasting your guys' time.